# Is it possible to customize the display dimensions in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, display, display-settings

Say my entire screen display is 20x20 cm, would it possible to shrink the display to something like 4 cm x 12 cm and ideally move the display anywhere on the monitor?

When shrinking, the behaviour should be as follows:

- For fullscreen applications, particularly games and videos, the display should shrink down and not just show a small portion of my screen.
- For windows such as browsers and Windows Explorer, it should not shrink at all and show the size as if the display was 20x20 cm.

A possible partial solution to this is to limit the dimensions of fullscreen applications rather than resize the entire display.

Answer (score 1):

Custom resolutions are sometimes achievable using the drivers/software for your graphics display hardware. Or by using third-party software such as this: https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU

Using the (deliberately well-hidden) customization capabilities of my Intel graphics
software on my former Windows Vista machine, I was able to create an active display
area of any size and position on my video screen. It was necessary to learn how to create suitable Detailed Timing Descriptors for my monitor to to that.